# What is the role of types.generated.go in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

What is the role of [types.generated.go](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/master/pkg/api/v1/types.generated.go)

1. What is it generated from?
2. What is it's usage?

I see a section in code like:

```
if yyq2[7] { z.EncSendContainerState(codecSelfer_containerMapKey1234)
```

what does things like `yyq2` are?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, k8s use [gengo](https://github.com/kubernetes/gengo) to generate code.

There are several project in kubernetes/cmd/libs/go2idl, such as go-to-protobuf, client-gen, set-gen,lister-gen.

1. K8s generate protobuf from go struct by go-to-protobuf. The generate script define in kubernetes/hack/update-generated-protobuf.sh
2. K8s generate client and util source code by client-gen, set-gen, lister-gen, the generate script define in kubernetes/hack/update-codegen.sh
3. K8s generate types.generated.go by [go/codec](https://github.com/ugorji/go), the generate script define in kubernetes/hack/update-codecgen.sh. The type in types.generated.go is for rpc serialization.